# Echo repeated variables loop php

Tags: php

you see, I have these variables that are set within a While, I'm using MySQL also, What I want to do is to sort of "Group" those variables into one, and then the rest of the variables that are not repeated, i want to assign them "Display:none" So , look at this image:
[image: Click here]

Now, as you can see there is two duplicate dates, but the values are different, so in this case (Take in mind that I only want to group these "Recibos" but dont worry about it) you can see in the first row it has a different date, and has no repeated dates, while the last two of "Recibos" is sort of duplicated

Basically what I want to do is to group the two last "Recibos" (The duplicate dates), only one of the same date has to appear, and the rest of them, are gonna be shown when the TR is hover

Though , I only want a simple version of what I want, it can be some sort of testing, as you can see in this image, i've been trying for weeks and still didnt get anything, I hope you can help me! thanks in advance
[image: Click to see the testing image]

I have made this code, which is the one in the image above:

Inside the while:

```
          $acumulado-=$monto;
          if(($fila>=$mostrar_de_aca_en_adelante && $detalles=='minimo') || ($detalles=='maximos')){
            $conteo++;
            $string_fecha[$conteo] = $fecha_operacion;
            $string_fecha_tmp[$conteo] = $fecha_operacion;
            $recibo_id_cliente[$conteo]=$id_cliente;
            $recibo_monto[$conteo]=$monto;
            $recibo_saldo_total[$conteo]=$saldo_total;
            $recibo_detalle_movimiento[$conteo]=$datos_detalles['detalle_movimiento'];
            $recibo_recibo[$conteo]=$recibo[0];
            $recibo_verificado[$conteo]=$datos_detalles['verificado'];
            $recibo_acumulado[$conteo]=$acumulado;
            $label = $monto;
          }
```

Outside the while:

```
echo "<br><br><br>";
for($i = 1; $i <= $conteo; $i++){
    if($string_fecha[$i] == $string_fecha_tmp[($i + 1)]){
      $label += $recibo_monto[$i];
      $string_imprime_tmp .= "<br>[Repetido]".$string_fecha[$i]."(".$label.")";
    }
}
echo $string_imprime_tmp;
var_dump($string_fecha);
```

By the way: I know this can be done in MySQL, but it can only be done in php i'm limited to php.

Comment: Maybe this should really be handled in MySQL.  Can you include your current query and some sample data?

Comment: You can use `array_count_values($string_fecha)` to get an array with the repetition counts of each date. Then find the one with duplicates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I had to put it in here, because I can't put so much characters, you are gonna find the query, and the code where the "Recibos" are shown: https://pastebin.com/60r4Txun

Comment: @Barmar
It seems like a good idea, it works so far, how can I find the duplicates one? Thanks. because I have done this and it doesn't show the duplicate ones:
$cuantos = array_count_values($string_fecha);
  var_dump($cuantos);

Comment: You should see `"12-04-2018 (09:32:032)" => 2` in that `var_dump`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. Is there a way to print the duplicates one? like, it works and shows only one date, but, is there a way to recognize the repeated dates? 
'31-03-2018 (10:15:47)' => int 1
  '12-04-2018 (09:32:02)' => int 2

Comment: Loop through the array and find the ones with count > 1.

Comment: `foreach ($cuantos as $date => $count) { if ($count > 1) ... } }`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, it works though, when it has 4 duplicated dates, the $count > 1 only shows one date, thanks.
I have done this:
$cuantos = array_count_values($string_fecha);
  echo "<br><br><br>";
  foreach ($cuantos as $date => $count) { 
    echo "<br>".$date;
    if ($count > 1){
      echo "<br>".$date;
    }
  }
By the way, how do put code tag in the comments?

Comment: Use backticks to mark code in comments.

Comment: The array returned by `array_count_values` has one entry for each date -- the key is the date, the value is the number of times that date is repeated.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks Barmar, I really appreciate your help. Would you help me out with something? The thing is that, as you read in my post, I want to group those two dates, which it's working fine, but I also need to sum the two columns of the repeated rows "Entrega", so... Basically, I need to save the repeated ones (The two last) in some kind of array or string, with display set to none with its "Entrega" value, and show only two rows (after doing the group thing on the two last repeated rows), so it will show the 31, and 12. And its value of "Entrega", the 12 should say: Entrega 2500. (sum)

Comment: Use an associative array where you hold the sum for each date. Loop over the original array, and add the values of the other columns to the corresponding entry.